# Llenar arreglo de caracteres ordenados de alfabéticamente C#

Tags: c#, array

Espero puedan ayudarme con lo siguiente.

Necesito llenar un arreglo de caracteres de manera ordenada respetando el siguiente orden **AaBbCcDdEeFfGg...Zz**

Los caracteres son ingresados por consola, hasta el momento tengo lo siguiente:

```
public void Insertar(char letra)
{
    int repetido = 0;
    
    if (puntero <= tamaño - 1) // Checar si hay espacio
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < puntero; x++) // Checar repetido
        {
            if (letra == arreglo_caracteres[x])
            {
                repetido++;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (repetido == 0) // No hay repetidos
        {
            int pos_insertar = -1;

            for (int x = 0; x < puntero; x++)
            {
                if (letra < arreglo_caracteres[x])
                {
                    pos_insertar = x;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (pos_insertar != -1) // Recorrer las numeros y agregar
            {
                for (int x = puntero; x >= pos_insertar; x--)
                {
                    arreglo_caracteres[x + 1] = arreglo_caracteres[x];
                }

                arreglo_caracteres[pos_insertar] = letra;
            }
            else // Insertar número en la ultima posición del arreglo
            {
                arreglo_caracteres[puntero] = letra;
            }
                    
            Console.WriteLine("Se inserto en la posición " + puntero);
                    
            puntero++;
        }
        else // Si hay repetidos no se inserta nada
        {
            Console.WriteLine("El número está repetido");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No hay espacio es para insertar el número");
    }
}
```

Pero eso me llena el arreglo de la forma **ABCDEabcde**.

Alguien que me de una idea de como resolverlo.

Comment: Hola josh, por fin resolviste?

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo la siguiente alternativa:

Para que no tengas que preocuparte por espacios vacíos ni longitud del arreglo usa listas e inserta los elementos en la lista sin preocuparte por el orden de los mismos (por ahora).

Entonces tu código podría quedar como:

```
public void Insertar(string letra, List<string> lista)
{
   lista.Add(letra);
}
```

Tu **función Insertar** recibe ahora dos parámetros, la letra a insertar, y la lista donde se insertará dicha letra.

Una vez que hayas hecho todas las inserciones correspondientes entonces nos ocuparíamos de ordenar los elementos de la lista como deseas:

```
lista.Sort(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Usando la **clase StringComparer** podemos escoger la forma en que queremos que se ordene nuestra lista, en este caso escogemos la opción **OrdinalIgnoreCase**, que ordena sin tener en cuenta las mayúsculas y minúsculas.

La **clase StringComparer** tiene las siguientes opciones:

```
StringComparer.InvariantCulture
StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
StringComparer.CurrentCulture
StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
StringComparer.Ordinal
StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase
```

Revisa cual se adecua a tus necesidades.

Revisa bien este código y si lo ves útil adáptalo a tus necesidades.

Comment: Hola Japv, gracias por responder. En parte funciona, pero cambiando el código ahora se ordena AabBcCdDeE.. y yo ocupo que primero sean las Mayúsculas. Alguna otra idea que me puedas aportar. Gracias nuevamente

Comment: @Josh revisa lo nuevo q puse